# Get file path of a resource (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

I had a SQL script in a file, added to my Xcode project, and I want get its file path.

When I write the following:

```
switch (var){
    case 1:
         NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"triggers.sql"];
    break;
```

I got the following error:

```
Expected expression
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show more lines of code

Comment: I got it… Seems to be, I cannot declare variables inside a switch statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To declare new variables inside a `switch` statement you need to create a 'block' for them to exist in:

```
switch (var){
    case 1:
    {
        NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"triggers.sql"];

        ...

        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try that:

```
NSString* databasePathFromApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"triggers.sql" ofType:nil];
//or
NSString* databasePathFromApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"triggers" ofType:@"sql"];
```